# dnlib library issue when trying to reference it into other project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-framework-version, de4dot

Using VisualStudio 2013 I've successfuly compiled the latest version of [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/) which is part of the [ConfuserEx](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/) and [de4dot](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) projects, the **dnlib** project by default targets .NET Framework 2.0 so it should be compatible to reference it in other projects that targets a greater version but when I reference the resulting **dnlib.dll** in a **new** project that targets a .NET framework greater than **3.0** the project can't compile.

There is **any** compiling error information just a VisualStudio messagebox that says:

> There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last
>   successful build?

I've tried the **dnlib.dll** in a (new, empty) WinForms project using both the debug and the release version of **dnlib.dll**, I've tried targeting FW 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 and 4.5.1 but the project has been compiled successfuly only targeting FW 2.0 and 3.0.

By the other hand, I'm totally able to navigate through the library members and instance the classes inside and all that, but no way to compile a project with that referenced **dnlib.dll**.

I think that if the default FW targeting in the dnlib project is **2.0** should be for a good reason 'cause it touchs external assemblies and that, so I'm not sure to try to solve this issue by increasing the FW targeting in the dnlib project, but anyways I've tried to increase it to **4.0** to see what hapens and I get a lot of compiler errors about type defs in **mscorlib.dll**.

I'm missing something?

How I can solve this problem to be able to compile a project that targets FW4.0 with the dnlib.dll that targets FW2.0 referenced?

Comment: I got some WARNINGs, but no errors when I change it to NET 4.0 - is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, fiddling around, I could get some `Warnings` but not errors.  As per MSDN, [`ExtensionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)  came into being with Net 3.0 and [`HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) with NET 4.0.  So, in order to make the NET 2.0 code compatible with 4.0 projects, it provides the missing Attributes.  The warnings are just that they are multiply defined, and since they are just Attributes, I don't think it matters.

Rather than comment them out, there are 2 easy ways to get rid of the Warnings.

Method 1 (better, I think): Create solutions for Net 2.0 and 4.0 builds.

Open the basic Net 2.0 solution.  Select the Solution (dnlib) in Solution Explorer.  On the File menu pick **Save dnlib.sln As** and use `dnlib20.sln` as the file name.  This is your NET 2.0 FrameWork Solution.

Do **Save As** again, this time to `dblib40.sln`.  This will be your Net 4.0 Framwwork solution in a moment.  Switch both the console test project and dnlib library projects to Net 4.0 Target platform.  Then, in Solution Explorer, exclude the last 2 files from the solution:  `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute.cs` and `ExtensionAttribute.cs`. Save it, clean and build, and you should be good.

You don't need these 2 files because NET has them defined (which is the warning); they are only meant for 2.0 projects/solutions.

Note:  You can also set it up so that the solutions compile to their own folders, so you dont get them confused.  On the Build Tab, next output add a folder(`..\Debug\bin\Net20` and `..\Debug\bin\Net40`).  You'll have to change/update for both Debug and Release versions.

Method 2: Define some conditional compiler constants.

Create `dblib20.sln` and `dblib40.sln` solutions as above (unless you dont want to even use 2.0).  Be sure to set the Framework to NET 4 in the 4.0 solution.

In the Net 2.0 dnlib **project** file, go to **Project Properties --> Build --> General** add the conditional compile symbol `NET20`.  Now, in `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute.cs` wrap the code there in a `#if`:

```
#if NET20

using System;
#pragma warning disable 1591    // XML doc warning

namespace System.Runtime.ExceptionServices {
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    sealed class HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute : Attribute {
    }
}

#endif
```

In `ExtensionAttribute.cs`, do the same thing.  Then Clean and Rebuild, and all should be well.  Since the symbol is only defined in the NET20 solution, those classes will only be compiled when you use/open the Net 2.0 solution.   If you download another update, you will have to redo this unless they provide a NET 4.0 solution file.

AFAIK, there still are not any built in FrameWork constants.

Finally, when those warnings are cleared away, there are 5 compare warnings, but from the looks of it, those can be ignored (the code seems to be doing what it wants).

Comment: The problem is not totally solved but I think this issue is easier to solve:

Comment: When compiling as Debug all goes ok but when I compile the NET40 project as Release, it throws me these kind of errors: `Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type` in here: `internal bool Equals(IModule a, Module b) {if (a == b)` and in other parts of the code, but the first parameter is an `IModule` interface not a `Module` so I'm not sure whether this is the proper way to solve the casting:  `if ((Module)a == b)` 'cause I can't do this: `if ((IModule)a == b)`

Comment: thats what I was talking about in the very last line -  this is a different issue.  the code looks to me like it is doing what it is supposed to do.  It is checking obj references to see if they are the same; the warning is that the code is not checking the value of those things.  Its just a warning, ignore it.

Comment: ...you might need to untick "treat warnings as errors" for it to compile.  There might be a better way to code that to remove the error, but I am not so familiar with what the code is doing that I would do that at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Change dnlib project's target version to .NET 4.0 Framework Client Profile.
Change the Example project target version to .NET 4.0 Framework Client Profile.
Remove/comment out ExtensionAttribute in ExtensionAttribute.cs in dnlib
Remove/comment out HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute in dnlib
I then compiled and got no errors.

I used Visual Studio 2012.